# What are parts of interface name called

Tags: interface

Consider this interface name `GigabitEthernet1/0/48`

I know that `GigabitEthernet` is an interface type. What does `1`, `0` and `48` stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are for the slot, subslot and port number.

This is mainly used by (and come from) Cisco routers, which are modular.

Those routers can have different cards inserted into a slot, so the final numbering will depend on the type of card inserted.

From [sunsetlearning.com](https://www.sunsetlearning.com/cisco-device-port-naming-convention/)

> The first thing you need to remember is the convention: slot#/port#.
>   With this convention it is indicating from less to more specific which
>   port you are referencing. The slot can be the device itself or a slot
>   for HWICs (High-Speed WAN Interface Card) or NMEs (Enhanced Network
>   Module). By default non-modular devices, or switches and routers that
>   have no extra slots for HWICs or NMEs, have only one slot, slot 0. So
>   all interfaces will be in slot 0, such as FastEthernet 0/0 or
>   FastEthernet 0/24. Devices that have expansion slots also have slot 0,
>   that is their built in ports. When you start plugging in modules, they
>   become slots 1,2,3….and so on. So with slot you are indicating where
>   the port is, either on the device, or on a card on the device. Then
>   comes the port number. So if I tell you to go configure port
>   GigabitEthernet 0/23 on a switch, you know that it is a built in port,
>   and it is the twenty-third one in.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the type of hardware equipment that you use.
In most case, it means `Number In Stack`/`Card or Slot` / `Port` . `SubInterface (like VLAN or IP SubNet)`